# How to set custom template for HTML formatter in Behat

Tags: behat

I tried in my behat.yml and put the template inside my /support dir, but no help.

```
    default:
      formatter:
        name:  html
        parameters:
          template_path: html.tpl
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend a custom class from the existing `HtmlFormatter` to explicitly set your html template.

**PHP**

```
namespace Behat\Behat\Formatter;
use Behat\Behat\Formatter\HtmlFormatter;

class MyHtmlFormatter extends HtmlFormatter {

    /**
     * The HTML template to use for formatting.
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getHtmlTemplate()
    {
        return '
          <div id="behat">
            {{content}}
          </div>
        ';
    }

    // You can override any other methods of HtmlFormatter that you want
    // to define custom behavior.
}
```

Then update your `behat.yml` file to point to your custom class.

**behat.yml** (Optional - Only needed if you don't use `--format` in your behat command line.)

```
default:
    formatter:
        name: Behat\Behat\Formatter\MyHtmlFormatter
```

**Behat**

Finally, run `behat` with the following command:

```
behat --out out.html your_feature.feature
```

If you want to specify this formatter directly then do:

```
behat --format Behat\\Behat\\Formatter\\MyHtmlFormatter --out o.html
```

Note that you need the `\\` to properly send the class name.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! But it doesn't seem to work... I made new php file for the custom formatter, added the file to bootstrap, updated behat.yml, but as I could see the custom formatter is never called. Does it work for you?

Comment: The command I'm using is

`behat --format html --out test.feature.html --config behat.yml test.feature`
I don't get any error, but the html template comes always from `HtmlFormatter`.

Comment: When you specify `--format html` you are forcing it to use the HtmlFormatter class. Call it like this `behat --format Behat\\Behat\\Formatter\\MyHtmlFormatter --out o.html` instead.

Comment: Btw. it doesn't work without the `--format Behat\\Behat\\Formatter\\MyHtmlFormatter` parameter. Not sure why, as I set the formatter in `behat.yml`, but it might be for new question;)

Comment: Or just using the Formatter from Emuse :)