# Is it possible for Behat JUnit formatter to show more lines from web page in case of scenario failure

Tags: junit, jenkins, behat

I am using Behat JUnit formatter in integration with Jenkins to publish testing results.
The problem is that it shows only a few lines from webpage in case if scenario has failed.

Typical failure report:[image: failure report]

It would be nice to see more lines (or even full web page) here, so it would be possible to catch the failure reason without reproducing failed scenario locally to get more details.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need create a custom formatter: See this [How to set custom template for HTML formatter in Behat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922825/how-to-set-custom-template-for-html-formatter-in-behat/13348651#13348651) answer which will tell you how to go about it.